# Web Form not recognizing PHP

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have built a webform with Laravel and have it working the way I want it to on my localhost. However, when I put it on the server my form stops recognizing my php commands. For example see below.

In my working model, my code looks like this.This is using javascript to return an array of data elements that I need for my project.

```
var pageDownloadInfo=<?php echo json_encode($project); ?>;
```

However when I put my form on the server an error occurs and it points to this in the console.

```
var pageDownloadInfo=<br />
```

and the console gives me this notice error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined variable: project in **C:\xampp\htdocs\QPA Form\resources\views\pages\datatest.blade.php** on line **278**
>   null;

The forms are exactly the same. I am not sure what is causing this.

Comment: Maybe the php.ini are different ?

Answer (score 0):

try using quotes around the echo statement as such

```
var pageDownloadInfo="<?php echo json_encode($project); ?>";
```

Comment: No that didn't work still gives an error. Am I possibly forgetting to download something? I don't think I am forgetting anything but it just isn't working.

Comment: try explicitly declaring the $project variable. Looks like that variable is never initialized.